# Actual and format argument lists differ in length

Tags: java

I am trying to create a selling menu but i am getting struggle. So this is my Product class:

```
import java.text.*;

public class Product {
    private String name;
    private int stock;
    private double price;

    public Product(String name, int stock, double price) {
        String[] itemName = {"Whiteboard Marker, Whiteboard Eraser, Black Pen, Red Pen, Blue Pen"};
        double[] itemPrice = {1.50, 5.00, 1.50, 1.50, 1.50};
        int[] itemStock = {85, 45, 100, 100, 100};
    }

    public String getName() {
        return "";
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Return true iff this product has at least n stock
     */
    public boolean has(int n) {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Sell n stock of this product (decrease stock by n)
     * and return the amount of money earned (price * n)
     */
    public double sell(int n) {
        return 0.0;
    }

    /**
     * Increase stock by n.
     */
    public void restock(int n) {
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name + " - " + stock + " at $" + formatted(price); 
    }

    private String formatted(double money) {
        return new DecimalFormat("###,##0.00").format(money);
    }
}
```

And then i have another class:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Store {
    private CashRegister cashRegister;
    private LinkedList<Product> products = new LinkedList<Product>();

    public Store() {
        products.add(new Product("Whiteboard Marker"));
        products.add(new Product("Whiteboard Eraser"));
        products.add(new Product("Black Pen"));
        products.add(new Product("Red Pen"));
        products.add(new Product("Blue Pen"));
    }

    private char readChoice() {
        return 'x';
    }

    private void sell() {
    }

    private void restock() {
    }

    private void viewStock() {
    }

    private void viewCash() {
    }

    private void pruneProducts() {
    }

    private String readName() {
        return "No Name";
    }

    private double readPrice() {
        return 0.0;
    }

    private int readNumber() {
        return 0;
    }

    private void help() {
        System.out.println("Menu options");
        System.out.println("s = sell");
        System.out.println("r = restock");
        System.out.println("v = view stock");
        System.out.println("c = view cash");
        System.out.println("p = prune products");
        System.out.println("x = exit");
    }
}
```

But when i tried to compile it appears "constructor Product in class Product cannot be applied to given types; required: java.lang.String,int,double; found: java.lang.String; reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length."
If you have any idea about this please explain to me. Thank you so much!

Comment: `Product(String name, int stock, double price) ` requires three values, `name` and `stock` and `price`, you're only supplying one

Comment: What do you mean i have supplied three values? Or did i supply it in a wrong way? @MadProgrammer

Comment: Look at the declaration of the constructor for `Product`, how many parameters does it have?  How many values are you passing?

Comment: Sorry i'm getting confused can you explain more please. @MadProgrammer